# Angular 2 custom directive with es5

Tags: javascript, angular, directive

I'm trying to build a custom directive / Angular 2 using vanilla es5.

Here is the code

```
(function(app) {

app.CustomDirective = ng.core.
    Directive({
        selector: 'test',
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function CustomDirective() {
            console.log('ds')
        },
        ngOnInit: function() {

        }
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

I declare it into the ngmodule

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppModule =
    ng.core.NgModule({
      imports: [ ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, ng.http.HttpModule ],
      declarations: [ app.AppComponent, app.CustomDirective],
      providers: [app.MyService ],
      bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

in The AppComponent

```
(function(app) {

    app.AppComponent = ng.core.
    Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: '//app/app.component.html',
      directives: [app. CustomDirective ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: [app.MyService, function AppComponent(myService) {
          this.myService = myService;
      }],

      ngOnInit: function() {
      }
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

and in the html

```
<h2 test >Test</h2>
```

But the console log i have in the constructor of the directive never gets fired.

If i declare it instead of the declarations array, to the providers array it gets called which is odd since it's a directive and because of that I can't access the elementRef for the element I apply the directive.

I'm using the latest angular 2 version as is in the package.json form the [quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html)

**UPDATE:**

I need to update this line

```
Directive({
    selector: 'test',
})
```

to this

```
Directive({
    selector: '[test]',
})
```

Comment: Please add a CodePen (http://codepen.io/pen/) or JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I'm not sure how to import the node modules into codepen or jsfddle :(

Comment: Use the one provided by the Angular team: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/js/plnkr.html

Comment: As it turns out I should put the selector attribute of ng.core.Directive in square brackets. I'll update the above post

http://plnkr.co/edit/8FqJvEznQx12Q7iUPtkx?p=preview